# ConvertFrom-Json returns "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid."

Tags: json, powershell, convertfrom-json

I face a problem when trying to convert a **valid** json-file into powershell-internal representation with the following code snippet:

```
[string]$changes = Get-Content -Path "C:\some\directory\with\file.json"
[PSCustomObject]$changes = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Changes
```

This triggers the warning `Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.`

The Powershell version in use is **v5.1** which does not even support a `Name` flag, so I am a bit confused and can't seem to find a solution.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: I am running powershell 5.1.17134.228 and I dont have a problem with the example json I used to test. do you mind to share the json you try to deserialize?

Comment: it contains sensible information, therefore I cannot share it :/ but it is definitely valid and conforms to all conventions.

Comment: no problem. was reading this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7 check if you have comments in your json.

Comment: the json-files are automatically generated, there are no comments inside (I checked again). json-format is not supportive of commenting anyways, I thought.

I thought about whether there are certain key-names that must not be used?

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1755

Comment: I reproduced updating my test json with an empty "key"

Comment: Yeah, I found an empty key in my document. thanks, I will provide this question with a correct answer once I sorted out my errors, unless you want to answer.

Comment: will answer yeah. glad to help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding this [thread](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1755), input json contains empty key(s) which look to be not supported by this powershell cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace string "" to custom name

```
$changes.Replace('""', '"_empty"') | ConvertFrom-Json
```

and then try to convert string to PSCustomObject